# How to remove Nan values while merging columns with their column name

Tags: python

I have this dataset

| Pink | Orange | Yellow |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Nan | Nan | Nan |
| 60 | Nan | Nan |
| Nan | 23 | Nan |
| Nan | Nan | Nan |
| Nan | 87 | Nan |

And I want this output

### |  Colors    |

| 60, Pink   |
| 23, Orange |
| 44, Yellow |
| 87, Orange |

I tried this code but I keep getting errors

```
df[‘Colors’] = [‘,’.join((df.columns[x]) for x,y in enumerate(list(i[-1])) if y !=Nan) for i in df.iterrows()]
```

Answer (score 0):

This code should provide the desired output

```
def get_colwise_notnull(df):
    toreturn = []
    for k in df.columns:
        this_col_val = df[k][df[k].notnull()]
        toreturn.append((k,list(this_col_val)))

    return toreturn
```

This would return a list where every element is a tuple. Each tuple represents a columns. The first element of the tuple is a column name and the second element is a list of all not null values.

If you want the output in the format u mentioned, u can further use the following function

```
def custom_output(col_list):
    for i in col_list:
        for ele in i[1]:
            print (ele,i[0], end = ' || ')
```